# When submitting coursework to a university does the author retain copyright?

Tags: copyright, united-kingdom

Does the author of university coursework retain copyright to it after submission?

Comment: What do you know about copyright? You're asking a lot of copyright questions that could be answered by reading [Section 11](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/48/part/I/chapter/I/crossheading/authorship-and-ownership-of-copyright) and [Section 16](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/48/part/I/chapter/II/crossheading/the-acts-restricted-by-copyright) of the UK Copyright Act.

Comment: Your questions would be greatly improved by removing your personal stories and motivations (big nose, pride in homework, weird car, sightseeing leading to wearing sneakers, new boiler, etc.) Just ask the legal question simply and clearly.

Comment: @Thedude: You have posted 15 questions in less than a day, a majority of which have close votes against them, and none of which seem to be earning you any rep.  Questions that boil down to, "Is this OK?" are not generally good questions for this site.  Please spend some time perusing the tour and help areas and perhaps reading well-rated questions before you continue this streak.

Comment: I think a great improvement to your questions would be to tag with an appropriate jurisdiction, otherwise a lot of people will look at it, shrug, and move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. Generally speaking, yes.

> ...some universities and colleges may ask that the students assign
>   their copyright over to the establishment when enrolling.
>   Alternatively, the establishment might extract a royalty free licence
>   for any works created as a condition of enrolment. **In the absence of
>   any such contract, the copyright would remain with the creator**.

https://www.gov.uk/guidance/ownership-of-copyright-works